# Query Performance Optimization in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-orm

I am creating a Blog website in django and while creating a page for specific blog posts I came across a problem in querying the data using the ORM.

I have a model for Post which is related to another model comments where all the comments are captured. The comments model have following fields ->

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField(null=True)
    Created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments_post')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments_user')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

Now while Querying the single blog post there could be N number of comments and for each comment there is a user assigned who has written the comment. So I want to find the user details such (name, email or phone number) for the user for each comment.

The Query that I have executed is ->

```
post = Post.objects.select_related().prefetch_related('images_set','comments_post').get(id=post_id)
```

Now when I try to use `{{comment.user.email}}` and if there are 3 comments for the post, the ORM will query 3 times to the DB to find the email for each user. But if I use `{{comment.user_id}}` it will query only once as it preloads the user_id as it is available in comments table.

Is there any way I can make only one query to the DB to get all the Names for all the comments?

Comment: Because of the `.select_related()`, it will fetch the data of the `user` in the same query, so `{{ post.user.email }}` will *not* make extra queries.

Comment: What is `post` in `{{ post.user.email }}`? A `Post` object, or a `Comment` object?

Comment: post is the post object which will contain all the details related to the blog post.

Comment: I need to find all the comments for the post and the related authors/users for those comments.

Comment: Sorry I updated the query I am using. I used Post instead of comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible `prefetch_related` foreign key inside foreign key. Such as `prefetch_related('comments_post__user')`, or If you want more performance you can use `annotate`. Annotate required field, It's more faster than `prefetch`

Comment: Wow man. It worked. The number of queries are same. 
Thanks man. Really appreciate it.

Comment: There's also [Prefetch objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) using which an even more efficient query could be written (Using select related inside the prefetch object)

Answer (score 1):

You can save an extra query to the database that fetches the user with a [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

post = Post.objects.select_related().prefetch_related(
    'images_set',
    Prefetch('comments_post', Comment.objects.select_related('user'))
).get(id=post_id)
```

This will make three roundtrips to the database: one for the `Post`, one for the `image_set`, and one for the `comments_post`. The last one will also fetch the data of the user, to prevent making an extra query for that.